# Combine Windbarbs with scatter in one chart highcharts

Tags: highcharts, scatter-plot

I use charts to which  I add series using a function as below:

```
function WindDirectionAddSeries(thisChart) {
        thisChart.addSeries({
            name: 'AverageBearing',
            id: 'AverageBearing',
            data: AverageBearing,
            color: '#0D6D9D',
            yAxis: 'Direction',
            type: 'scatter',
            zIndex: 5,
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' '
            }
        }, false);
        thisChart.addSeries({
            name: 'WindBarbs',
            xAxis: 1,
            color: 'red',
            type: 'windbarb',
            visible: true,
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: true,
                units: [
                    ['hour', [3]]
                ]
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormatter() {
                    return this.series.name + ': ' + (this.value / 0.27778).toFixed(1) + ' km/h'
                }
            },
            data: WindBarbData
        }, false);
    }
```

The data array's are of similar lengths and for line types and area types etc... this method works fine. Only the scatter series type fails. When adding the Windbarbs series the addSeries function call does not return and other javascript async functions start failing as if memory get overwritten.

Is it fundamentally possible to combine scatter and windbarb series?

If yes: what do I do wrong/what is the requirement?
If no: can this be a request?

NB: the code is what I actually use. I already tried reducing parameter settings to the bare minimum but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your issue correctly, but there is a mistake in the config that may cause it. The `yAxis: 'Direction'` doesn't really exist in the API, so it should be removed. Also, if you don't use a second xAxis in the chart (I'm not able to check it without seeing the full config), the code `xAxis: 1` should be also removed. Check the demo below:

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9dpLcsvk/

Comment: Actually, the code I gave of course is only part of the system i.e. there is a yAxis with an id  'Direection' and there is a second xAxis to get the windbarbs on top of the chart. So I created a jsfiddle for one chart according to the system I use (with only little data): https://jsfiddle.net/HansR/zu5wL309/  I hope this clarifies.

Comment: OK. Worked a bit more and the problem seems to be in "<script defer src='https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/windbarb.js'></script>". If I do this with defer it fails, if I remove defer it runs.

Comment: But having said the above, it still does not work in my operational environment which is slightly more complex.

Comment: Thank you for providing a simplified config. For sure, scatter and windbarb can be combined and since everything works correctly in the example demo (after changing `desrc` to `src` https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bw0crz67/), it seems to be the issue in your internal project, not related to Highcharts.